# Restricting "auth" hash function OpenVPN will use for HMAC

Tags: openvpn

We have a few OpenVPN 2.5 servers running on VMs, simulating some scenarios a product of ours have had to deal with. We run tests against them. One of these scenarios is a server that would only accept SHA-1 as the hash function for HMAC generation.

I have added `auth SHA1` to the `server.conf` of this specific server. However, if I try to connect with a client that requests SHA-256, they execute some kind of negotiation and end up using SHA-256. That's excellent in general, because it makes the whole connection safer. However, for our testing purposes, we would rather have it to fail.

Is there a way to force OpenVPN to accept one and only one hash function? In special, one that is not that up-to-date?